# Python3 AWS Lambda - Making a post request to a domain that requires a VPN

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing a python3 AWS Lambda function and I need to make a POST request from this lambda to a web app. This web app is under a domain that requires a VPN to access. Due to this, the lambda is unable to make the POST request - it just loads forever until timing out. If I make the POST request to the web app through postman, instead of the lambda, while I am connected to the VPN, it works in less than a second. But, I need this lambda because every couple of weeks, it is run to get data from an s3 bucket.

The reason why I am not using API gateway (which would be the ideal option) is due to the 29 second time limit. Lambdas can run for longer than 29 seconds, and I need at least a few minutes for it to run because it needs to iterate through nearly all of the files in our S3 bucket.

Would greatly appreciate some advice on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it woudl be worth calling it an AWS lambda in the subject. Lamba can also mean an anonymous function in python.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your Question to provide more information about your architecture? For example, where is this web app hosted (is it on AWS)? You say that the POST only takes a second, but then you say that Lambda might take more than 29 seconds. More importantly, what are you actually trying to _achieve_, from a business viewpoint? That is, can you describe it in terms of outcomes rather than the bits that would make it run?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VPC, set up VPN connection to the target site, set up routes in VPC's route table, and then launch Lambda function in that VPC.

Implementation will depend on your network architecture, but this would be a good starting point: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html